# Content Approval status changes to pending

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 list with content approval enabled and versioning disabled. I have attached a SPD workflow to the list. When i create a new item the status of the item is 'Pending' as expected and workflow completes. when I approve the item I notice that the "Approval Status" changes to pending when the workflow is running and the "Approval Status" is set to pending once workflow completes.

I believe when the workflow runs logically it assumes as the item is updated and hence the status changes to "Pending"... is that correct?

I want to perform some action when approval status is "Approved", but when the workflow runs it's always 'Pending' even though the item is Approved from SharePoint List.

Is there a workaround to this scenario?